# Input is a self closing tag. Or not?

Tags: html, web-standards

As we know `input` is a [self-closing tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp). I thought the same.

However, a while ago I read [Web Fundamentals about Semantics and accessibility tree](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/the-accessibility-tree) and found such an interesting example:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">Receive promotional offers?</input>
</label>
```

This example doesn't meet the html5 validator requirements and seems not valid however I used to trust Google developers.

Is this a correct syntax? Some upcoming standards or a simple typo?

Comment: My money is on it being a documentation bug. The surrounding text says "put the input inside the label" and not "put the text inside the input" - I think the person typing the HTML had a brain-fart.

Comment: I think that is invalid - input was only ever "closed" for xhtml and then it only used the `/>` ending and not an actual closing tag

Comment: But they have two options as examples. One is valid and second is this one. Also, similar code you can find if you check their example through the Dev Tools

Comment: Don't trust him. He's no engineer. Input ever was and is closing itself.

Comment: "I used to trust Google developers" — Ha. They play **very** fast and loose with the rules of HTML.

Comment: @Pete — Using `</input>` was fine in XHTML. It's only if you followed Appendix C for compatibility with HTML parsers that you *had* to use empty element syntax. Even than, it wasn't allowed content so `<input></input>` was fine but `<input>something</input>` was not.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML5 "Living specification" at the time of writing (2020-01-02) says that [the `input` element has a "Nothing" content-model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element), which means [it cannot contain content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing). So Google's documentation is wrong.